# Web timer using Python

Tags: python, timer

I would like to create web page which will print simple message

```
x minutes to shutdown
```

where 'x' would decrease once a minute automatically without clicking 'refresh' in web browser. The value will be counted from data downloaded from SNMP source (that is why I wanted to use Python). AFAIK I should use Javascript (am I right ?).

Is it possible to use Python to this sort of task (dynamic web page)? If not what other language would you suggest ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is the only language the works well on the web. So yes, you have to use it.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a scripting language of your choice to load the initial time on the server side, and just serve your page with a Javascript timer that modifies the time every minute.

You would need to look into the `setTimeout()` Javascript function to manage the timer.

Something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

      var timer = setTimeout ( "changeTime()", 60000 );

      function changeTime(){
          //modify time logic 

          clearTimeout ( timer );
          timer = setTimeout ( "changeTime()", 60000 );
      }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not very Web 2.0, and also discouraged by the W3C, but you could add this to your HTML header:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60" />
```

That will automatically refresh the page for you every 60 seconds without the user having to click refresh.

To implement this you would create a [CGI script using Python](http://docs.python.org/library/cgi.html), which gets the result via [SNMP](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/) and generates the webpage with your message. If this script also outputs the [meta refresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) above, it will be updated by the browser every minute, generating the new content.

The proper way of doing this is probably using [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)). It all depends on how much time you want to spend on it.